# Slow Query when compare datetime fields but fast when use string to compare (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(a.Date,'%d/%m/%Y') as data, a.DateTIni, a.DateTEnd, (SELECT count(eepv.id)
                            FROM eventos_extension AS eepv
                            WHERE eepv.idEvento = 1
                            AND eepv.dataHoraEvento between a.DateTIni AND a.DateTEnd) AS visits, 

                           (SELECT count(eee.id)
                            FROM eventos_extension AS eee
                            WHERE eee.idEvento = 3
                            AND eee.dataHoraEvento between a.DateTIni AND a.DateTEnd) AS redirects,

               (SELECT  count(distinct ees.idUnicoEx)
                            FROM eventos_extension AS ees
                            WHERE ees.idEvento = 3
                            AND ees.dataHoraEvento between a.DateTIni AND a.DateTEnd) AS unique_redirects

from (
select  curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date,
        DATE_ADD(curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY, INTERVAL '00:00:00' HOUR_SECOND) as DateTIni,
        DATE_ADD(curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY, INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR_SECOND) as DateTEnd

from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) a
where a.Date between "2014-04-21" and "2014-04-21"
ORDER BY a.Date
```

This query takes around 6 seconds to execute on a Table with 10mm

But, If I change the comparison inside the subqueries to the same date in string format it takes only 0.219s

Like this

```
select DATE_FORMAT(a.Date,'%d/%m/%Y') as data, a.DateTIni, a.DateTEnd, (SELECT count(eepv.id)
                            FROM eventos_extension AS eepv
                            WHERE eepv.idEvento = 1
                            AND eepv.dataHoraEvento between '2014-04-21 00:00:00' AND '2014-04-21 23:59:59') AS visits, 

                           (SELECT count(eee.id)
                            FROM eventos_extension AS eee
                            WHERE eee.idEvento = 3
                            AND eee.dataHoraEvento between '2014-04-21 00:00:00' AND '2014-04-21 23:59:59') AS redirects,

               (SELECT  count(distinct ees.idUnicoEx)
                            FROM eventos_extension AS ees
                            WHERE ees.idEvento = 3
                            AND ees.dataHoraEvento between '2014-04-21 00:00:00' AND '2014-04-21 23:59:59') AS unique_redirects

from (
select  curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date,
        DATE_ADD(curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY, INTERVAL '00:00:00' HOUR_SECOND) as DateTIni,
        DATE_ADD(curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY, INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR_SECOND) as DateTEnd

from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) a
where a.Date between "2014-04-21" and "2014-04-21"
ORDER BY a.Date
```

What am I doing wrong in the first one?

I need to execute this query with an interval of 7 days, if each day takes 0.219s is ok, but 6s takes more than 40s to finish.

Comment: You are surprised that using constants is faster than a correlated subquery?  For one thing, with the constants, the subquery could be evaluated only one time because the results are always the same.

Comment: Perhaps try storing your computed date range values in a temp table and Joining to that from your initial query?  Trying to compute it in the query sounds highly inefficient.

Comment: Gordon, even if I execute Once is slower

You have a point Siyual, I'm just trying not to do it, but in the last case could be a solution